# Probability that none of 3 tennis balls chosen at random have been used before

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

There are 15 tennis balls in a box, of which 9 have not previously been used. 3 of these balls are randomly chosen, played with and then returned to the box. later, another 3 balls are randomly chosen from the box. Find the probability that none of these balls has ever been used.

I have decided to go simpler way and I have solved this problem another way:
$$ (9/15)*(8/14)*(7/13)*(6/15)*(5/14)*(4/13)$$ and I got the answer 0.008114962

But book gives another answer - $0.083$.

Did I solve the problem right? If not, tell me please where I have made a mistake.

Comment: First it should be $\frac{7}{13}$. Is the question regarding the last 3 balls or all of them?

Comment: It was misprint, sorry:)
I think, that regarding all of them

Comment: I think you are correct and the answer is wrong.

Comment: Probability to choose 3 not previously used balls from 15 when 9 are not previously used: $$\frac{9\cdot8\cdot7}{15\cdot14\cdot13}.$$ Conditionally on this, probability that these 3 balls were not played with because they would have been chosen in the first phase: $$\frac{12\cdot11\cdot10}{15\cdot14\cdot13}.$$ Thus, the desired probability is $$\frac{12\cdot11\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7}{(15\cdot14\cdot13)^2}\approx.0893.$$

Comment: "Find the probability that none of these balls has ever been used" cannot apply to the three first balls chosen since these are played with.

Comment: @cr001 You might wish to be *much* more careful when posting comments.

Comment: I would actually say that the wording of the problem means "all $6$ balls are never chosen before they are first played" because otherwise all $6$ balls are used at some point and hence the probability would be $0$.

Answer (score 5):

In the answer below, $n$ represents the number of unused balls chosen in the first phase:

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{3}\frac{\binom{9}{n}\cdot\binom{15-9}{3-n}}{\binom{15}{3}}\cdot\frac{\binom{9-n}{3}}{\binom{15}{3}}\approx0.089$$